# How to union when using matching

Tags: union, cakephp-3.0, matching

I am trying to list public status posts and friends posts

getting friends post

```
$friendsPosts= $this->Posts->find('all')
        ->contain(['Users', 'Languages', 'PostStates'])
        ->matching('Users.Dusers', function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['Dusers.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
        });
```

getting public post

```
$posts= $this->Posts->find('all')
        ->where(['Posts.post_state_id' => 3])
        ->contain(['Users', 'Languages', 'PostStates']);

$posts->union($friendsPosts);
dd($posts->toArray());
```

error message: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()
                ->where(['Posts.post_state_id' => 3])
                ->contain(['Users', 'PostStates', 'Languages', 'Tags', 'Translations' => ['Users', 'Languages', 'conditions' => ['post_state_id' => 3]]]);

        $friendsPosts = $this->Posts->find('all')
                ->where(['Posts.post_state_id' => 2])
                ->contain(['PostStates', 'Languages', 'Users', 'Tags', 'Translations' => ['Users', 'Languages', 'conditions' => ['post_state_id' => 3]]])
                ->innerJoinWith('Users.Dusers', function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['Dusers.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'UsersUsers.status' => 1])->select($this->Posts->Users);
        });
$posts->union($friendsPosts);
```